# Removing an element from TreeMap cloned object is not removed from main treemap object in java

Tags: java, clone, treemap, shallow-copy

I read the following logic about `TreeMap`:

The `TreeMap.clone()` method returns the shallow copy of the `TreeMap` instance. In the shallow copy, object B points to object A location in memory. In other words, both object A and B are sharing the same elements. The keys and values themselves are not cloned.

Considering this correct, I made a program as per the link [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wRIi.png) in which I removed an element from the `treemap` cloned object and my expectation was that this element must have been removed from main treemap object too but it didn't happen. I checked the key's hashcode too for both object but it was the same. Can someone please let me know, a shallow copy is something different in TreeMap or my understanding is something incorrect? Jdk - 1.8

Comment: Shallow copy means that the object referenced by the original is identical with the object in the copy. The references themselfes which point to the object are not. By removing a reference from one tree the other reference is not affected - even if both point to the same(identical) object. (Btw please include your code here, thanks!)

Comment: I think what you are saying is deep copy.  I have provided my code in the link given in description. Thanks!!!

Comment: No! in a deep copy the refernced objects are also cloned in a shallow copy not. In a shallow copy the references are cloned but not the objects referenced by them. (That is: only the Tree itself gets cloned)

Comment: For the code: linked code can vanish, making it difficult future readers to follow. Therefore better include it here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is somewhat incorrect (from my p.o.v...sry!:)

My understanding is "key and values are same", but the **cloned maps are not (same)**!
And being part of a map is an information, which nor the key nor the value "knows about", but only the maps/containers... and this information is (copied &) owned by each map, after cloning.

I would agree with your misunderstanding / observation, if you would have checked the `Map.Entry<K, V>`s ... (these are also unknown to the underlying keys & values).

And after cloning, you/someone must ensure it, if you want the clones to be *synchronized*.

---

If you *indeed* want "two references" of the same map (the expected behavior), you "just" share/pass the reference to this map (but watch out for concurrency, "usual" Map implementations are not thread safe):

```
 //not: Map<X, Y> copy = original.clone(), but:
 Map<X, Y> ref = original; // then all changes on "original" are "reflected" at "ref" ..
```

---

Under "deep copy", I'd understand, that "keys and values" (and even deeper) get cloned, too.